# paymentMethodID payment method id cannot be blank

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce3, plugin-commerce-stripe

We're using Craft Commerce 3.2.11 and Stripe as the payment gateway.  We can put through a purchase using test cards no problem, but when we try with an actual card we get the message:

paymentMethodID payment method id cannot be blank

Is there anything else we need to do to put through a live card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: it looks like it was an issue with the secure cert on the site.  Once we got that updated, purchases are going through as normal.